# Compiling 32-bit vs 64-bit project using CMake

Tags: 64-bit, linker, cmake

How do I specify that CMake should use a different `link_directories` value depending on whether the target is 32-bit or 64-bit? For example, 32-bit binaries need to link with 32-bit Boost, 64-bit binaries need to link with 64-bit Boost.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You do something along these lines

```
  if( CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8 )
    set( BOOST_LIBRARY "/boost/win64/lib" )
  else( CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8 )
    set( BOOST_LIBRARY "/boost/win32/lib" )
  endif( CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8 )
  set( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS ${BOOST_LIBRARY} )
```

Comment: As specified by Martin, this shouldn't be needed for boost, but it is a good to know method anyway.

Comment: What were the cmake developers thinking with the else ( ... ) part of the syntax.  That's not an else if BTW.  confused me for a moment until I remembered this.  New cmake syntax doesn't need the else, endif stuff in brackets.

Answer (score 13):

I know it's quite old question. But it's still on top when you search with Google "cmake 32 64".
I have answer similar to user434507's answer but a little bit more readable in my opinion (I don't like if-else construction in cmake, it looks ugly):

```
math(EXPR BITS "8*${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P}")
set(BOOST_LIBRARY "/boost/win${BITS}/lib")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS ${BOOST_LIBRARY})
```

This will point `BOOST_LIBRARY` path to /boost/win**32**/lib or /boost/win**64**/lib, depending on your architecture.

Comment: Error: CMake Error at build.cmake:27 (math):
  math cannot parse the expression: "8*": syntax error, unexpected $end,
  expecting exp_OPENPARENT or exp_NUMBER (2)

Comment: there is TINY error in second line. Not {$BITS} but ${BITS}.  $ sign before brackets.

Answer (score 4):

For Boost specifically, you should use

`FIND_LIBRARY(Boost 1.44 COMPONENTS ...)`

Then the CMake variable Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS will contain the correct library path, which has to be set using LINK_DIRECTORIES, e.g.

`LINK_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})`

The more general case is correctly described in user434507's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on rominf I turned up following solution (for Windows).
I install boost libraries into: C:\Boost_32 and C:\Boost_64

In CMakeLists.txt

```
math(EXPR BITS "8*${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P}")
set(BOOST_ROOT C:/Boost_${BITS})  

find_package(Boost 1.64.0 COMPONENTS ... )

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}  )
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})
```

Explanation:

- `CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P` is equal to 4 on 32bit platform, and 8 on 64bit platform.
- Expression `8*${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P}`  will evaluate to 32 or 64,
  respectively.
- `C:/Boost_${BITS}` turns into `C:/Boost_32` or `C:/Boost_64` automagically

Advantages:

- You don't need conditionals (and in my CMakeLists there are too many already),
- It is 90% how you 'should' include Boost with CMake.

Comment: CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P is always blank for me :(
I believe you need to run try_compile before it has a valid value.

Comment: try make CMakeLists.txt with these 2 lines:"project(check_for_sizeof_void_p)  
message( ${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P} )"   And run "cmake ."

Comment: I fixed the issue. I think my antivirus was preventing various things occuring. I moved it out of a protected directory and into a path without spaces (maybe it was that too) and all good. Strange...