# CMAKE output directory depending on generator architecture

Tags: cmake

Assuming that the person building the targets will use the appropiate generator (see [CMake Multiarchitecture Compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334095) ),

How can I specify the output directory accordingly.

Something like:

```
if(WIN32)
    if(64bit)
       set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ./DEBUG/win64)
    elseif(32bit)
       set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ./DEBUG/win32)
    endif()
endif()
```

and so on for `if(UNIX)` and `if(APPLE)` which probably the same answer will work given CMake phylosophy.

Note that I'm not talking about cross-compiling. And assuming the generator is known.

Comment: What exactly are you asking about? `32bit` and `64bit` could be determined using `CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P`, for example.

Comment: @Angew Yes, that would do it. I also saw that approach here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029587/compiling-32-bit-vs-64-bit-project-using-cmake
but I was hoping there was a more elegant way. Furthermore on the cmake mailing list there were some complains regarding the variable not being set. That would indeed be a solution though.

Comment: Would it also correctly set 32bit if we're running cmake with 32-bit generators on a 64bit machine?

Comment: For Visual Studio generators, it works (I've tested it). I don't think other generators have 32-bit/64-bit variants.

Comment: Good! I'll test it on the unix. They are able to build 32 and 64, see the link on the question.

Comment: I've testing this on unix also with `cmake 2.6` it works fine.