# Android CMake link pre-built libraries

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake, shared-libraries, sdl-2

I've built SDL for Android with ndk-build and Android-Make-Files. Now I want to find these libraries in my CMakeLists.txt. The libs are found here:

```
lib/
    SDL/
        arm64-v8a/
        armeabi/
        armeabi-v7a/
        x86/
        x96_64/
```

Each directory contains `libSDL2.so`.
How can I load all these libraries in CMake and naming them `SDL2_LIBRARY`?
My current approach is

```
set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR lib/SDL/include)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})

FIND_LIBRARY(SDL2_LIBRARY NAMES libSDL2.so PATHS lib/Android/SDL/armeabi-v7a)
```

(I don't even know how to find all of them and not just `armeabi-v7a`.)

EDIT:
Since building for all plattforms is not possible, what is wrong with my usage of FIND_LIBRARY?

Comment: Using several libraries with the same name **at once** looks very strange: what you are trying to achive with that? As for finding files, you may use command [file(GLOB_RECURSE)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/file.html), like `file(GLOB_RECURSE SDL2_LIBRARY "lib/Android/SDL/armeabi-v7a/*/libSDL2.so")`, But again, the whole intention seems weird for me.

Comment: It also seems weird to me, but NDK puts all those library into the APK, if built with Android make for support of more platforms.

Comment: With CMake you can build only for **single platform** at once. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44343091/cmake-project-for-jni#comment75695830_44343091).